# How to install GIMP 2.8 in Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: gimp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get GIMP 2.8?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134035/how-do-i-get-gimp-2-8)

I have seen repositories for Ubuntu 11.x and 12 but not for Ubuntu 10.10.... How can I install GIMP 2.8 on my Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick? I don't want to compile anything....